# How to manually add time or date in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask, is there a way I can manually input a specific time or date in mysql database?

I'm using `addtime()` and `adddate()` but the results are `0000`

here is my table type:

```
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Number_of_days | varchar(3) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Date_In        | date       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Time_In        | time       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and this is my command

```
INSERT INTO Date_And_Time_In (Number_of_days, Date_In, Time_In) VALUES ('02', 'DATE(2013-06-03)', 'TIME(12:10:00)' );
```

and here's the output

```
mysql> select * from Date_And_Time_In;
+----------------+------------+----------+
| Number_of_days | Date_In    | Time_In  |
+----------------+------------+----------+
| 01             | 2013-06-03 | 11:32:24 |
| 02             | 0000-00-00 | 00:00:00 |
+----------------+------------+----------+
```

the first one was from the `curdate()` and `curtime()`. I'm just trying to experiment though what if I want to change a specific time or date what mysql command what I use?

Answer (score 0):

When you add quotes around MySQL functions, they are not executed (because you have turned them into a string); and any invalid date value will result in `0000`. Remove the quotes and it should work great.

```
INSERT INTO 
    Date_And_Time_In (Number_of_days, Date_In, Time_In)
    VALUES ('02', DATE(2013-06-03), TIME(12:10:00));
```

Comment: Hi there! I tried that one but it give me this:                  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':10:00) )' at line 1

Comment: Good, now you can read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) so you can figure out what is wrong and fix it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the DATE() and TIME() functions around those values. MySQL accepts those formats and puts them in correctly.  See below:

```
INSERT INTO Date_And_Time_In (Number_of_days, Date_In, Time_In) VALUES ('02', '2013-06-03', '12:10:00' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the date and time functions. Just out the literals in quote.http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/insert-date.html link has lots of example.